# Cannot subset columns inside a nested data.frame

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have a data.frame that contains several character columns but also a data.frame. Thus, I have a data.frame inside of my data.frame. My goal is to subset one character column together with a column that is inside the nested data.frame. But, whenever I try to subset the nested column by name, it states it doesnt exist. You can see the data.frame here:

```
df = structure(
  list(
    `$id` = c("21", "22", "23"),
    Id = c("159347",
           "161863", "22646"),
    Name = c("159347", "161863", "22646"),
    SumPeriod = structure(
      list(
        AccPeriodBasTwrAtMarketPrice = c(0.0969367972082358, 0.537983489472227,-0.107066381156318),
        AccPeriodLocTwrAtMarketPrice = c(0.0969367972082358,
                                         0.537983489472227,-0.107066381156318),
        BopDate = c(
          "2022-02-28T00:00:00",
          "2022-02-28T00:00:00",
          "2022-02-28T00:00:00"
        ),
        BopBasHoldingValueAtMarketPrice = c(7592266.52,
                                            5135960.59, 7166815.5),
        BopBasInterestAccrual = c(0, 0, 0),
        EopDate = c(
          "2022-02-28T00:00:00",
          "2022-02-28T00:00:00",
          "2022-02-28T00:00:00"
        ),
        EopBasHoldingValueAtMarketPrice = c(7599626.22,
                                            5163591.21, 7159142.25),
        EopBasInterestAccrual = c(0, 0,
                                  0),
        AccPeriodBasTwrAtExposureValue = c(0.0969367972082358,
                                           0.537983489472227,-0.107066381156318),
        AccPeriodLocTwrAtExposureValue = c(0.0969367972082358,
                                           0.537983489472227,-0.107066381156318),
        AccBasIrr = c(0.0969367972082358,
                      0.537983489472227,-0.107066381156318),
        AccLocIrr = c(0.096936797208258,
                      0.537983489472227,-0.107066381156318),
        AccBasMwr = c(0.0484449181280957,
                      0.268270120259021,-0.0535618639528656),
        PeriodBasIrr = c(0.0969367972082358,
                         0.537983489472227,-0.107066381156318),
        PeriodLocIrr = c(0.096936797208258,
                         0.537983489472227,-0.107066381156318),
        PeriodBasTwrAtMarketPrice = c(0.0969367972082358,
                                      0.537983489472227,-0.107066381156318),
        PeriodLocTwrAtMarketPrice = c(0.0969367972082358,
                                      0.537983489472227,-0.107066381156318),
        PeriodBasTwrDeposit = c(0,
                                0, 0),
        PeriodBasTwrWithdrawal = c(0, 0, 0),
        PeriodBasTwrDepositWithdrawal = c(0,
                                          0, 0),
        PeriodBasTwrDividendTax = c(0, 0, 0),
        PeriodBasTwr = c(7359.70000000112,
                         27630.6200000001,-7673.25),
        PeriodBasMwr = c(0.0484449181280957,
                         0.268270120259021,-0.0535618639528656),
        BenchmarkCalcType = c(
          "BenchmarkNotCalculated",
          "BenchmarkNotCalculated",
          "BenchmarkNotCalculated"
        ),
        EopBenchmarkName = c("",
                             "", ""),
        AccBasBenchmarkReturnPct = c(0, 0, 0),
        PeriodBasBenchmarkReturnPct = c(0,
                                        0, 0)
      ),
      class = "data.frame",
      row.names = c(NA, 3L)
    ),
    Series = list(
      structure(
        list(
          AccPeriodBasTwrAtMarketPrice = 0.0969367972082358,
          AccPeriodLocTwrAtMarketPrice = 0.0969367972082358,
          BopDate = "2022-02-28T00:00:00",
          BopBasHoldingValueAtMarketPrice = 7592266.52,
          BopBasInterestAccrual = 0,
          EopDate = "2022-02-28T00:00:00",
          EopBasHoldingValueAtMarketPrice = 7599626.22,
          EopBasInterestAccrual = 0,
          AccPeriodBasTwrAtExposureValue = 0.0969367972082358,
          AccPeriodLocTwrAtExposureValue = 0.0969367972082358,
          AccBasIrr = 0,
          AccLocIrr = 0,
          AccBasMwr = 0.0968429207825055,
          PeriodBasIrr = 0,
          PeriodLocIrr = 0,
          PeriodBasTwrAtMarketPrice = 0.0969367972082358,
          PeriodLocTwrAtMarketPrice = 0.0969367972082358,
          PeriodBasTwrDeposit = 0,
          PeriodBasTwrWithdrawal = 0,
          PeriodBasTwrDepositWithdrawal = 0,
          PeriodBasTwrDividendTax = 0,
          PeriodBasTwr = 7359.70000000112,
          PeriodBasMwr = 0.0484449181280957,
          BenchmarkCalcType = "BenchmarkNotCalculated",
          EopBenchmarkName = "",
          AccBasBenchmarkReturnPct = 0,
          PeriodBasBenchmarkReturnPct = 0
        ),
        class = "data.frame",
        row.names = 1L
      ),
      structure(
        list(
          AccPeriodBasTwrAtMarketPrice = 0.537983489472227,
          AccPeriodLocTwrAtMarketPrice = 0.537983489472227,
          BopDate = "2022-02-28T00:00:00",
          BopBasHoldingValueAtMarketPrice = 5135960.59,
          BopBasInterestAccrual = 0,
          EopDate = "2022-02-28T00:00:00",
          EopBasHoldingValueAtMarketPrice = 5163591.21,
          EopBasInterestAccrual = 0,
          AccPeriodBasTwrAtExposureValue = 0.537983489472227,
          AccPeriodLocTwrAtExposureValue = 0.537983489472227,
          AccBasIrr = 0,
          AccLocIrr = 0,
          AccBasMwr = 0.535104714457055,
          PeriodBasIrr = 0,
          PeriodLocIrr = 0,
          PeriodBasTwrAtMarketPrice = 0.537983489472227,
          PeriodLocTwrAtMarketPrice = 0.537983489472227,
          PeriodBasTwrDeposit = 0,
          PeriodBasTwrWithdrawal = 0,
          PeriodBasTwrDepositWithdrawal = 0,
          PeriodBasTwrDividendTax = 0,
          PeriodBasTwr = 27630.6200000001,
          PeriodBasMwr = 0.26827012025902,
          BenchmarkCalcType = "BenchmarkNotCalculated",
          EopBenchmarkName = "",
          AccBasBenchmarkReturnPct = 0,
          PeriodBasBenchmarkReturnPct = 0
        ),
        class = "data.frame",
        row.names = 1L
      ),
      structure(
        list(
          AccPeriodBasTwrAtMarketPrice = -0.107066381156318,
          AccPeriodLocTwrAtMarketPrice = -0.107066381156318,
          BopDate = "2022-02-28T00:00:00",
          BopBasHoldingValueAtMarketPrice = 7166815.5,
          BopBasInterestAccrual = 0,
          EopDate = "2022-02-28T00:00:00",
          EopBasHoldingValueAtMarketPrice = 7159142.25,
          EopBasInterestAccrual = 0,
          AccPeriodBasTwrAtExposureValue = -0.107066381156318,
          AccPeriodLocTwrAtExposureValue = -0.107066381156318,
          AccBasIrr = 0,
          AccLocIrr = 0,
          AccBasMwr = -0.107181136120043,
          PeriodBasIrr = 0,
          PeriodLocIrr = 0,
          PeriodBasTwrAtMarketPrice = -0.107066381156318,
          PeriodLocTwrAtMarketPrice = -0.107066381156318,
          PeriodBasTwrDeposit = 0,
          PeriodBasTwrWithdrawal = 0,
          PeriodBasTwrDepositWithdrawal = 0,
          PeriodBasTwrDividendTax = 0,
          PeriodBasTwr = -7673.25,
          PeriodBasMwr = -0.0535618639528656,
          BenchmarkCalcType = "BenchmarkNotCalculated",
          EopBenchmarkName = "",
          AccBasBenchmarkReturnPct = 0,
          PeriodBasBenchmarkReturnPct = 0
        ),
        class = "data.frame",
        row.names = 1L
      )
    )
  ),
  class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA,
                3L)
)
```

So in the data.frame above, the only columns I am interested in having is "Id" and "EopBasHoldingValueAtMarketPrice" where the latter is a column inside the nested data.frame called "SumPeriod".I try to achieve this by:

```
df_subset = subset(df, select = c("Id", "SumPeriod$EopBasHoldingValueAtMarketPrice"))
```

But I get the error:

```
frame`(x, r, vars, drop = drop) : undefined columns selected
```

Have you folks any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have anything named `"SumPeriod$EopBasHoldingValueAtMarketPrice"`, that's an expression to extract a column from `SumPeriod`.  @Stephan gave you a `dplyr` solution; here's a base R solution:

```
df1 <- subset(df, select = c("Id", "SumPeriod"))
df1$SumPeriod <- subset(df1$SumPeriod, select = "EopBasHoldingValueAtMarketPrice")
```

This keeps the structure as a nested dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

`SumPeriod` is a dataframe within your dataframe. So you are suggesting `dplyr` in your tags, you can solve it with this approach:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  unnest(SumPeriod) %>% 
  select(Id, EopBasHoldingValueAtMarketPrice)
```

Output is:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  Id     EopBasHoldingValueAtMarketPrice
  <chr>                            <dbl>
1 159347                        7599626.
2 161863                        5163591.
3 22646                         7159142.
```

Comment: Hi @Stephan, thanks for the feedback! I do get a weird error: Error:
! Assigned data `map(data[[col]], as_df, col = col)` must be compatible with existing data.
x Existing data has 3 rows.
x Assigned data has 27 rows.
i Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.

Answer (score 2):

`data.table`  approach

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(df)
DT[, .(Id, 
       EopBasHoldingValueAtMarketPrice = lapply(Series, function(x) x$EopBasHoldingValueAtMarketPrice))]
#        Id EopBasHoldingValueAtMarketPrice
# 1: 159347                         7599626
# 2: 161863                         5163591
# 3:  22646                         7159142
```

Answer (score 1):

If you feel comfortable with `dplyr`, then use Stephan's solution. If you need a base solution, you can just you assign the needed variable from the nested frame to the parent frame, then use `subset()`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df["EopBasHoldingValueAtMarketPrice"] <- df$SumPeriod$EopBasHoldingValueAtMarketPrice
df_subset <- subset(df, select = c("Id", "EopBasHoldingValueAtMarketPrice"))
df_subset
#>       Id EopBasHoldingValueAtMarketPrice
#> 1 159347                         7599626
#> 2 161863                         5163591
#> 3  22646                         7159142
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason for a data frame inside the data frame? You could have this stuff all in a simple data frame

```
x <- df$SumPeriod
y <- df$Serie
y <- rbind(y[[1]],y[[2]],y[[3]])

df <- cbind(df[,c("Id","Name","$id")],x,y)
```

Then, your suggested subset works

```
df_subset = subset(df, select = c("Id", "EopBasHoldingValueAtMarketPrice"))
```